# PHP retrieve object's getter methods only once in an array of objects

Tags: php, oop, object

I've got an array of 20 objects that are all the same. These objects are all the same and contain a couple of properties and some getters and setters. I'm converting the property data to an HTML table like so:

```
public function addBody($objects) {        
    $ret = (string) NULL;

    foreach($objects as $object) {
        $ret .= '<tr>';

        $methods = get_class_methods($object);        
        foreach($methods as $method) {
            if(strpos($method, 'get') !== false) {
                $ret .= '<td>' . call_user_func(array($object, $method)) . '</td>';
            }
        }

        $ret .= '</tr>';
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

I'm iterating through my array of objects and then I get all methods of each object where I filter on only the getters (with strpos). The function works but retrieving all object methods is a waste of time. A solution I could think of is getting the first object and retrieve all its methods (getters) and use that in my addBody function.

Would this be a good solution of is there a better one?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but seems like broken software design for me. Could you give us some context?

Comment: @ksno Could be :P So I'm retrieving 20 records from a database. Then I'm setting 4 columns of each record to the same Domain Enitity's properties using setters. Then I collect these 20 objects in an array which I then use to convert to an HTML table. I'm trying to grasp on the repository pattern: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129742/my-take-on-implementing-the-repository-design-pattern-in-php .

Comment: [The Repository Pattern](http://shawnmc.cool/the-repository-pattern), a nice post. The part _setting 4 columns of each record to the same Domain Enitity's properties using setters_ is unclear for me. 20 objects: if those 20 objects are of the same class, you already know the methods, why to search for getters? Just call them.

Comment: The function 'addBody' is inside my HTMLTablePrinter class. This class would accept any array of objects, so I need the function to be dynamic because there will be more tables that I need to display on my website.

Comment: `HTMLTablePrinter` class seems to have **print** html tables, but not create them `:]` and why would it accept **any** array of objects? What if one object has method `getName()` and another does'nt, but has `getAge()` instead ? Your 'printer' would _create_ the output you would not like to have.

Comment: I meant to say any array of the same objects. And I would have to rename my HTMLTable class I guess. I'm still figuring things out and always thinking of automating as much as possible. The same with a generic collection class that collects the same objects. If I **know** all objects will be the same, would this be a proper way to create table rows?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by better but I posted an answer which makes the same thing different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this:

```
public function addBody($objects) {
    $ret = '';
    $obectMethods = get_class_methods(current($objects));
    $methods = array_filter($obectMethods, function($method) {
        return strpos($method, 'get') !== false;
    });

    foreach($objects as $object) {
        $ret .= '<tr>';

        foreach($methods as $method) {
            $ret .= '<td>' . call_user_func(array($object, $method)) . '</td>';
        }

        $ret .= '</tr>';
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

First we retrieve methods from first object and use them in foreach loop.

Comment: This works, but as ksno just pointed out, I might be getting into broken software design.

Comment: @Beeelze Whatever _broken software design_ means, if you change the rules of your design, you just need a new design ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your definition of better, but sure there is another one... Less code and one getter to access any property for your specific case.

Our simple entity:

```
class myEntity {
   private $name;
   private $age;

   public function __get($property) {
      if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
         return $this->$property;
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

and then in your method:

```
public function addBody($entities, $properties) {        
    $ret = '';

    foreach($entities as $entity) {
        $ret .= '<tr>';
        foreach($properties as $property) {
           $ret .= '<td>' . $entity->__get($property) . '</td>';
        }
        $ret .= '</tr>';
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

where you have a list of entities:

```
$entities = array ( new myEntity(), new myEntity()); 
$properties = array ('name', 'age');

var_dump($object->addBody($entities, $properties));
```

Comment: I see you are using the magic __get() method. I've heard both bad and good things about them. I was actually trying to avoid them if possible.

Comment: for small task isnt necessary for sure